# SublimeCodeIntel Canopy modules autocompletion

Tags: macos, virtualenv, sublimetext3, canopy, sublimecodeintel

I am using Sublime Text 3 with CodeIntel plugin on OSX Mavericks. I have installed Canopy and set the env so that I can simply use it from Terminal.app. In Sublime, I want the Canopy's modules to be recognized and auto-completed as I type. So far it only works for python packages OSX comes with. For example when I do

```
import
```

CodeIntel makes an autocompletion list and Sublime shows this popup, but this list does not include any Canopy modules such as pandas, even though they are installed. To proove I have a working pandas I did:

```
import pandas; help(pandas)
```

and hit Build in Sublime. It showed me help documentation of pandas. In addition, when I do:

```
import sys; print(sys.path)
```

it shows me canopy paths.

I have read about .codeintel/config file and tried various paths such as adding the /Library/path to Canopy lib/site-packages. in pythonExtraPaths in .codeintel/config , but it did not resolve the issue.

If you have any recommendations or previous relevant experience about this issue, it would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I switched to Sublime 2 and tried again. everything works as expected. I cannot figure out whether this problem relies on Sublime Text 3 or the CodeIntel package.

Answer (score 0):

Canopy is a virtual env, so you could search for "sublime virtualenv", or click this:
http://matthewphiong.com/sublime-codeintel-configuration-for-virtualenv

Comment: Caution: Canopy uses venv not virtualenv, though they are very similar. See https://support.enthought.com/entries/21802240-Use-venv-not-virtualenv-with-Canopy-Python